# Time evolution of wave function in QM

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hamiltonian, time-evolution

Recently I've been studying quantum dynamics with Sakurai's modern quantum mechanics, but I am confused with why the time evolution operator is written as

$$U(t,t_0)=\exp\left[\frac{-iH(t-t_0)}{\hbar}\right]$$ 
for time-independent Hamiltonian, while 
$$U(t,t_0)=\exp\left[-\left(\frac{i}{\hbar}\right)\int_{t_0}^tdt'H(t')\right]$$
 for time-dependent (commuting case). My thought is that, since we can Taylor expand the wave function at $t=t_0$

$$\begin{align}\psi(x,t)&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}\left(\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right)^n\psi(x,t)\bigg|_{t=t_0}\right) (t-t_0)^n\\ 
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}\left(\left(\frac{-iH}{\hbar}\right)^n\psi(x,t)\right)(t-t_0)^n\\
&=e^{\frac{-iH(t-t_0)}{\hbar}}\psi(x,t)
\end{align}
$$

we only need to know the value of $H$ at $t=t_0$. If this is true, then $U(t,t_0)=\exp\left[\frac{-iH(t-t_0)}{\hbar}\right]$ should hold whether $H$ is time-dependent or not. What have I done wrong here?

Comment: Where are you getting that the $n^\text{th}$ derivative is $(-i H / \hbar)^n$?

Comment: Since $H\psi=i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\psi$, we have $H=i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$, then $\left(\frac{-iH}{\hbar}\right)^n=\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right)^n$. Correct me if I'm wrong, thanks.

Comment: @Rick Pan, the equation for derivative $\partial_t \psi =1/(i\hbar)H\psi$ holds only for $\psi$. It does not necessarily hold for its derivatives.

Comment: @JánLalinský Thanks for the comment. If we assume that the eigenstates of $H$ forms a complete basis, then we should be able to expand its derivatives with the complete basis. If this is the case, the relation should also hold for its derivatives right?

Comment: @RickPan, no, the relation does not hold because of the  reason yuggib pointed out - the expansion coefficients are functions of time as well. Canonical momentum operator $p_x$ is always expressible as $-i\hbar\partial_x$, whatever the function $\psi$ may be, but the Hamiltonian is not always given by $i\hbar\partial_t$; it only holds for special functions - solution to time-dependent Schroedinger equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first remark is that, at a rigorous level, you are not allowed to do all those manipulations freely. However, let's suppose for a moment that you would, for everything is extremely regular and well-behaved.

The (omitted) starting hypothesis is that
$$i\partial_t\psi(t)=H(t)\psi(t)\; .$$
If we iterate the derivation, we do not get simply $H(t)^2\psi(t)$, but rather (this is a simple application of the product rule, that actually works also in this case)
$$(i\partial_t)^2\psi(t)=i\dot{H}(t)\psi(t)+H(t)^2\psi(t)\; .$$
As we can easily see, this is where the OP's argument goes wrong, since the derivative of $H(t)$ does not vanish in general for time dependent operators.

I want to remark again, however, that this **is not** the proper way of dealing with these type of time-dependent equations. The proper way is, however, very complicated and it requires a lot of advanced functional analysis. If you are curious, the most common method is due to T.Kato, and can be found e.g. in this [book](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4612-5561-1).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm curious that if we expand $\partial_t \psi$ with eigenstates of $H$ (which is usually assumed to form a complete basis), don't we get $H^2\psi=(i\partial_t)^2 \psi$?

Comment: You could only use eigenstates for a fixed $t$, but they would not be eigenstates, in general, for another $t'\neq t$ (since $H(t')\neq H(t)$), and as well not eigenstates for $\dot{H}(t)$. Really, this is not the good way of thinking about that... ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It is true that eigenstates can change with respect to $t$, but I'm expanding the series at a fixed $t$, how is that not applicable?

Comment: Let $\psi_{n,t}$ be an eigenvector of $H(t)$; however in the expansion you have $\dot{H}(t)\psi_{n,t}$, and $\psi_{n,t}$ is not an eigenvector for it.

Comment: What if we consider $H^2\psi=H(i\partial_t\psi)=i\partial_t(i\partial_t\psi)$, why is this incorrect?

Comment: Why on the world would $H$ be equal to the time derivative? The time derivative is just an abbreviated expression for $\partial_t \psi(t)=\lim_{h\to 0}h^{-1}(\psi(t+h)-\psi(t))$ (provided the limit exists). A family $(H(t))_{t\in\mathbb{R}}$ is a family of self-adjoint operators. In your first equality, you are just using the property that we suppose $\psi(t)$ to be solution of a differential equation, namely $i\partial_t\psi=H\psi$. Now, that **does not, in any way,** imply that $i\partial_t\psi$ would be a solution of the same equation as well.

Comment: Let $i\partial_t\psi=\sum c_k \psi_k$ where $\psi_k$ are eigenvectors of $H$(by completeness of eigenstates). Then $H(i\partial_t\psi)=\sum c_k H \psi_k=\sum c_k (i\partial_t)\psi_k=i\partial_t(i\partial_t \psi)$. Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: @RickPan Yes, for in general for a time dependent $H(t)$, the coefficients $c_k$ would depend on time as well as the functions $\psi_k$...believe me, this is not true/correct ;-)